# Mail not sending with multiple attachements using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments, multiple-file-upload

I have created a form where users enter data and upload files(form1.php). Once the submit button is clicked, the data is inserted into the database and the uploaded files are saved into the server(insert.php) with a preview of the fields that are entered by the user. Upon confirmation, a mail is sent with the attached files.

```
**FORM1.PHP**
<form action="insert.php" action = "form-to-email.php" name="frmAdd" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-inline clearfix">
            <label class="col-md-5">Select A File To Upload:</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="file" name="myfile[]" id="Uploaded_file" multiple=""/> 
                </div>
        </div><br/>
<div class="form-inline clearfix">  
            <label class="col-md-5">Name of the Administrator </label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="Admin_name" class="form-control" Required><br/>
                </div>
        </div><br/>

 **INSERT.PHP**
 <?php
 //If directory doesnot exists create it. 
 $output_dir = "uploads/";

 if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
 {
 $ret = array();

$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
{

    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
    {
        $RandomNum   = time();

        $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
        $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

        $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
        $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
        //$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
        $ImageName      = $ImageName;
        //$NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $ImageName);
         //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];


             $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
    }
    else
    {
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            //$ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $ImageName      = $ImageName;
           // $ImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            $result[$ImageName]=$ImageName;
            //$ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$ImageName;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$ImageName );
        }
    }
}
echo $uploadresult=json_encode($result);
}
?>
/*Hidden fields to carry the file name to the next phppage to send as an attachment */
 <form action="mail1.php" method="Post" >   
 <input type="text" name="Upload1" value="<?php echo ($uploadresult); ?>">
 </form>

 **MAIL1.PHP**
 <?php  
 $Upload1=$_POST['Upload1'];
 $filepath="C:/app/apache24/htdocs/Uploads/";
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $email_body = "body";

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                
$mail->Host       = "***********"; 
$mail->SetFrom('******');
$mail->Subject    = "System Configuration ". $formno ."";
$mail->MsgHTML($email_body);
//$address="*********";
$mail->AddAddress($address);
$mail->addAttachment("uploads/$Upload1");
if($mail->Send()) 
{
    echo "Success";
    echo $Upload1;
}
else echo "ERROR IN SENDING MAILS";

}
exit;
?>
```

My question is, how do I send these file names to mail1.php so that they can be attached and sent in mail?

Appreciate any suggestions :) Thanks! :)

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer, so update it. Compare your code with what's done in [this example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response :) I had tried that code and it works for me.  But that is not exactly what I want. I have 3 steps in my form.
1.)The user fills in the form(form1.php)
2.) The values are inserted into the database, a preview is shown to the user and Uploads are saved in a folder.(insert.php)
3.)A mail is sent with the uploads as attachment.(mail1.php)
I am fine till the 2nd step. The multiple uploads are saving in a folder. How do I call it to the 3rd step so that they are sent as an attachment in the mail? I want a code only for MULTIPLE uploads for single upload I hv a solution

Comment: When tracking down a bug you need to divide it up into separate problems - if you try to do everything at once you won't know where the problem is. Take the example and add one thing at a time.